# Is it easier to calculate a factorial or the inverse of a factorial (1/n!) for extremely large n?

Tags: number-theory, factorial

I need to calculate extremely large factorials but they grow extremely fast! I was wondering if it might be easier to calculate $\frac{1}{n!}$ rather than n! itself because as n goes to infinity $\frac{1}{n!}$ goes to zero, which I think may be easier to calculate. Is it easier to calculate the factorial or the inverse of it?

Comment: What do you mean by "calculate"?

Comment: If you want an approximation, the Stirling approximation is good. if you want number-theoretic properties, a more explicit description of the problem would be useful

Comment: +1 Stirling approximation. I can't think of any practical (but this is where the more explicit description would be useful) applications where you absolutely must have an exact factorial when `n` gets large.

Comment: $n!$ is an integer, while $1/n!$ is (to a computer) an infinite decimal that must be truncated. If your goal is an exact calculation, integer arithmetic is far superior to floating point. - In general, I don't think your intuition is correct: things that are close to zero aren't necessarily easier to calculate than things that are not.

Comment: Write a C programme.

Comment: $n!$ will be more easier to compute because it is an integer. Even though there are tons of library of arbitrary precision arithmetic for both integers and fractions around. Being known to be a integer allow a more efficient implementation for $n!$. Furthermore, there are more ways to perform integer arithmetic. e.g. using modular arithmetic and Chinese remainder theorem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The period of the repeating decimal of $\frac{1}{n!}$ can be very large, closer to $n!$ than to the number of digits in $n!$.  For example, [$\frac{1}{19!}$ has period $81648$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2F19%21) even though there are only $18$ digits in $19!$ itself.  And we would need to calculate $36$ digits of $\frac{1}{19!}$ to see that it differs from $\frac{1}{19!+1}$.  So this doesn't seem like a very promising strategy.

Answer (score -2):

why do you want to calculate n! in the first place?
most times you will devide it by other factorials and then it is better to wait with calculating till the formula contains as least factors as  possible 
for example if you have to calculate n! / ((n-k!) X k!) don't start with calculating n!

Comment: "why do you want to calculate n! in the first place?" That seems like a weird question to ask about such a basic and ubiquitous mathematical function.  Perhaps the OP wants to know the number of permutations on an $n$-element set, for instance?